# PHP Variables disappearing

Tags: php, mysql, forms

```
    echo $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $uid;
$querytotal = "update customer_det set `t1` = $t1, `t2` = $t2, `t3` = $t3, `t4` = $t4 WHERE `id` = $uid "; 
echo $querytotal;
```

So I echo the variables, and I see them fine.  When I go to do the update statement and echo the statement afterwards, it drops all the variables.  I have no idea how that's even possible.  Mysql_error: ...for the right syntax to use near ' `t2` = , `t3` = , `t4` = WHERE `id` =' at line 1.  So it's skipping error on t1, but then kicks out at t2?  Is there something i'm missing here?

Here's the echo'd query before it's ran `update customer_det set`t1`= '215',`t2`= '240',`t3`= '265',`t4`= '300' WHERE`id`= '273'`

and after `update customer_det set`t1`= '',`t2`= '',`t3`= '',`t4`= '' WHERE`id`= ''`

Comment: what are the data types of the columns?

Comment: It's trying to update with rounded integer values, and the column types are INT(15)

Comment: Why are you not using PDO/MySQLi and prepared statements? That eliminates 90% of all PHP/MySQL problems on SO.

Comment: First of all I don't know how to implement either of those.  Second, it is my task to finish what was started.  The server runs without MySQLi module in PHP 4

Comment: Do you have the query inside a function, and echoing it outside the function?

Comment: @coder1984 I'm starting to think this is a serious scope issue, because there's a ton of function blocks and it's overwhelming

Comment: there you go, good luck debugging :)

Comment: I think i'm going to need it...this is getting ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $uid;
$querytotal = "update customer_det set t1 = '$t1', t2 = '$t2', t3 = '$t3', t4 = '$t4' WHERE id = '$uid' "; 
echo $querytotal;
```

You need to have 'single quotes' around your variable names inside the "double quotes" in php for them to show

Comment: try doing the string in a java-like format then `String str = "Hello" + variable +" World";`

Comment: Permesan What's that mean? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: `"update customer_det set `t1` = "+t1+", `t2` = "+$t2+", `t3` = "+$t3+", `t4` = "+$t4+" WHERE `id` = "+$uid;`

Comment: You're missing the single quotes in your last comment

Comment: Oh and my mistake use the period . symbol instead of +

Comment: Well, that is strange. What are the values of the variables after you execute? Are those also empty? If so then during your query execution those are some how getting changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $uid;
$querytotal = "update customer_det set t1 = '{$t1}', t2 = '{$t2}', t3 = '{$t3}', t4 = '{$t4}' WHERE id = {$uid}"; 
echo $querytotal;
```

Variables are not being dropped. Your query is just not correct.

Comment: If you think that this answer is correct, feel free to check this answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> echo $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $uid;
>   $querytotal = "update customer_det set t1 = '". $t1 ."', t2 = '". $t2 ."', t3 = '". $t3 ."', t4 = '". $t4 ."' WHERE id = ". $uid; 
>   echo $querytotal;